# BrowserMob + selenium + java. How to create new response filter during on test scenario?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browsermob

I need to create one more response filter during one test scenario. But now when I do this both filters work at the same time. How could I stop or override the previous one without stopping current browser instance?

Code example:

```
proxy.addResponseFilter((response, contents, messageInfo) -> {
        if (messageInfo.getOriginalUrl().contains(keyWord)) {
            contents.setTextContents(newResponse);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to remove a javascript filter after you've added it, unfortunately. The new REST API that is currently in development will support this, though. There's an issue open to track this: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/326

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll follow up this issue.